# Swiftkotlin command line not found for converting Swift to kotlin

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, kotlin

I am using Swift kotlin for converting swift code to kotlin which is working on Xcode project but when I am trying to execute from mac terminal it shows SwiftKotlin not found .
Github link: https://github.com/angelolloqui/SwiftKotlin

```
-bash: swiftkotlin: command not found
Vivek-Mac-mini:~ vivekrawat$
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to install the package into

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

folder on your Mac, so the terminal can treat it like other command-line commands like cd, open, etc.

> From Xcode, run the desired target and copy the generated executables (you can find it under the Products generated folder) in a directory with executable rights for later use. Typically, you could use:
>   swiftkotlin command line tool: /usr/local/bin/

To do so, you can try the following:

1. in the left pane of Xcode find the last folder called Products, open it. There should be a file with .app extension.
2. try to drag the file with .app extension from XCode to your desktop, holding `alt` key on the keyboard.
3. open Finder, click `Shift+Cmd+G` and paste `/usr/local/bin/` into the prompt
4. drag the file from your desktop to that folder
5. restart the Terminal and try to use the command again